# How to present a (no nib) ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I've created a ViewController (without nib files), so how do I load this viewController in the app delegtate? my current code is:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
viewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init...]; // I use a custom init method
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

And how can I use the presentModalViewController method to show new view controllers of the same "CustomViewController" class?

THANKS for the help!

NOTE: By the way, I do see that this code does call my initialization method, and my ViewDidLoad method in my customViewController is being called however the screen is still black....

Comment: Did you try setting the new view controllers frame and maybe setting a background colour to start debugging?

Comment: Did you create a view property for this view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, I was just missing this code in my viewDidLoad Method:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

So everything was working, but the screen by default is black and without a frame.

Comment: Do not add that to your init method but to the viewDidLoad method, otherwise you are breaking the lazy loading of the viewController's view.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your properties are not set up correctly.

Check this line:

```
viewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init...]; // I use a custom init method
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

check that self.viewController is okay, and there's nothing stopping you from just doing:

```
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do just that in one of the apps I'm working on. Try typecasting your view controller

```
CDViewController *viewController = (CDViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
viewController.managedObjectModel = self.managedObjectModel;

// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
```